# JQuery string contains check

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, comparison, contains

I need to check whether a string contains another string or not?

```
var str1 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
var str2 = "DEFG";
```

Which function do I use to find out if str1 contains str2?

Comment: a **benchmark** of different solutions can be found here: http://jsben.ch/#/RVYk7

Comment: @EscapeNetscape: Nice to see a benchmark link. If I change the observation string to a very long `UTF-8` multibyte text, the results change drastically? Also, the results changed with change in position of substring in the observation string. BTW, which one were you suggesting.

Answer (score 295, accepted):

You can use javascript's [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) function.

```js
var str1 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
var str2 = "DEFG";
if(str1.indexOf(str2) != -1){
    console.log(str2 + " found");
}
```

Comment: this would works only when substring has exact match, will not work around "DEfG" as f is small case.

Comment: @RedSwan: you could convert the string to uppercase or lowercase and then do the comparison, problem solved.

Comment: [`indexOf()` is not supported in IE < 9](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8848097/339874)

Comment: @mulllhausen: It's 2016, this answer is 6 years old, and most sites have stopped supporting IE < 9.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: fair enough. I just commented because it wasn't mentioned in any of the answers on this page and people may be interested to know.

Comment: For clarity, you should use === instead of ==

Comment: @DeepSojitra jQuery is not a language.  It's a JavaScript library.  The jQuery library does not contain this function, it's part of the JavaScript language.  Also this question is 11 years old and this answer was accepted.

Comment: @RedSwan or you could also use `indexOf("DEfG", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`

Answer (score 17):

```
var str1 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
var str2 = "DEFG";

sttr1.search(str2);
```

it will return the position of the match, or -1 if it isn't found.

Comment: It would be nice to note that [Array.prototype.search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) implicitly converts the string to a regular expression which may not give the desired result.

Comment: Last row should be: str1.search(str2); not sttr1, IMHO

Answer (score 10):

Please try:

```
str1.contains(str2)
```

Comment: CurrentPage.contains is not a function

Comment: It's because .contains() is a jQuery method.

Comment: I get `contains is not a function`

Comment: That's how it's done $(":contains('Hello')")

Answer (score 9):

I use,

`var text = "some/String";
text.includes("/") <-- returns bool; true if "/" exists in string, false otherwise.`

Answer (score 5):

If you are worrying about Case sensitive change the case and compare the string.

```
 if (stringvalue.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf("mytexttocompare")!=-1)
        {

            alert("found");
        }
```