# How to check if a string contain specific words?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$a = 'how are you';
if (strpos($a,'are') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

In PHP, we can use the code above to check if a string contain specific words, but how can I do the same function in JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript : string contains ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/javascript-string-contains)

Comment: and [JQuery string contains check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728022/jquery-string-contains-check)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see if string contains substring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480771/how-to-see-if-string-contains-substring)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you are looking for exact *words* and don't want it to match things like "nightmare" (which is probably what you need), you can use a regex:

```
/\bare\b/gi

\b = word boundary
g = global
i = case insensitive (if needed)
```

If you just want to find the characters "are", then use `indexOf`.

If you want to match arbitrary words, you have to programatically construct a RegExp (regular expression) object itself based on the word string and use `test`.

Answer (score 74):

you can use indexOf for this

```
var a = 'how are you';
if (a.indexOf('are') > -1) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

**Edit**: This is an old answer that keeps getting up votes every once in a while so I thought I should clarify that in the above code, the `if` clause is not required at all because the expression itself is a boolean. Here is a better version of it which you should use,

```
var a = 'how are you';
return a.indexOf('are') > -1;
```

Update in ECMAScript2016:

```
var a = 'how are you';
return a.includes('are');  //true
```

Comment: very bad answer. this will fail: 'howare you'

Comment: @vsync Why you said "bad answer"? Because he removed IF-statement? Well, what is your opinion about pre-edited? (before editing)

Comment: @Shafizadeh - not because of the `if`. did you even read my answer to understand why using `indexof` is bad in this context? why did you even think it's because if the `if` anyway?

Answer (score 49):

### `indexOf`/`includes` should not be used for finding whole words:

A word (in western culture) is a drawing of a symbols close to each other, with some space between each word. A word is considered as such if it's a **complete** piece of characters draw together and **not a partial** part of it:

```js
"has a word".indexOf('wor')  // 6 ("wor" is not a word in this sentence)
"has a word".includes('ha') // true ("ha" is not a word in this sentence)
```

---

#### Check if a single word (*whole* word) is in the string

Find a **real whole** word, not just if the letters of that word are somewhere in the string.

```js
const wordInString = (s, word) => new RegExp('\\b' + word + '\\b', 'i').test(s);

// tests
[
  '',            // true
  ' ',           // true
  'did',         // true
  'id',          // flase
  'yo ',         // flase
  'you',         // true
  'you not'      // true
].forEach(q => console.log(
  wordInString('dID You, or did you NOt, gEt WHy?', q) 
))

console.log(
  wordInString('did you, or did you not, get why?', 'you') // true
)
```

#### Check if all words are in the string

```js
var stringHasAll = (s, query) => 
  // convert the query to array of "words" & checks EVERY item is contained in the string
  query.split(' ').every(q => new RegExp('\\b' + q + '\\b', 'i').test(s)); 


// tests
[
  '',            // true
  ' ',           // true
  'aa',          // true
  'aa ',         // true
  ' aa',         // true
  'd b',         // false
  'aaa',         // false
  'a b',         // false
  'a a a a a ',  // false
].forEach(q => console.log(
  stringHasAll('aA bB cC dD', q) 
))
```

Comment: I had a chance where I need 2 check if "How are you?", "Are you crazy?" contains the string "are"(case insensitively) and not contains "Awareness is important". In such a case, this function is so helpful @vsync :)

Comment: Make sure the "word" does not contain any regex meta characters or the match will not work.  Any regex meta characters in the word must be escaped.

Comment: +1 for adding the way to make the word you're looking for a variable. Most other answers I found offered a fix pattern...

Comment: Well I read your answer and it can be fine :-) ! +1. btw I think using `indexOf` is fine either, because [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480771/how-to-see-if-string-contains-substring#3480785) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring#1789952) are two great answers from two profesional persons that both of him have used `indexOf`.

Comment: @Shafizadeh - those answers you have referred to do not apply to this specific question, where an `indexOf` solution will fail, regardless of how "professional" those who gave those answers are.

Comment: Would be nice to complete this answer with the case if you need to check some words in the string. In general you need to change this string `query.split(' ').every(q => new RegExp('\\b' + q + '\\b', 'i').test(s)); ` to this `query.split(' ').filter(String).some(q => new RegExp('\\b' + q + '\\b', 'i').test(s)); `. You need to filter the query for removing the empty strings like `''` from array like `['a', '', '']` in case the query is `a  ` because empty string is a substring of any string.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, I would change the order of parameters: `const wordInString = (word, s) => ...`. I've just used this function (thanks for the answer!), and failed in the parameters order. It seems like `wordInString` should require word then string, not string then word. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

You're looking for the indexOf function:

```
if (str.indexOf("are") >= 0){//Do stuff}
```

Answer (score 6):

You might wanna use **include** method in JS.

```
var sentence = "This is my line";
console.log(sentence.includes("my"));
//returns true if substring is present.
```

PS: includes is case sensitive.

Answer (score 6):

In javascript the includes() method can be used to determines whether a string contains particular word (or characters at specified position). Its case sensitive.

```
var str = "Hello there."; 

var check1 = str.includes("there"); //true
var check2 = str.includes("There"); //false, the method is case sensitive
var check3 = str.includes("her");   //true
var check4 = str.includes("o",4);   //true, o is at position 4 (start at 0)
var check5 = str.includes("o",6);   //false o is not at position 6
```

Comment: Thanks! This is simple solution

Answer (score 5):

An easy way to do it to use Regex match() method :-

For Example

```
var str ="Hi, Its stacks over flow and stackoverflow Rocks."

// It will check word from beginning to the end of the string

if(str.match(/(^|\W)stack($|\W)/)) {

        alert('Word Match');
}else {

        alert('Word not found');
}
```

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8KVC/11999/)

NOTE: For adding case sensitiveness update the regex with `/(^|\W)stack($|\W)/i`

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This will

```
/\bword\b/.test("Thisword is not valid");
```

return `false`, when this one

```
/\bword\b/.test("This word is valid");
```

will return `true`.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var str1 = "STACKOVERFLOW";
var str2 = "OVER";
if(str1.indexOf(str2) != -1){
    console.log(str2 + " found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a conditional **ternary operator**

```
str = 'I am on StackOverflow';
str.match(/(^|\W)StackOverflow($|\W)/) ? 'Found. Why lie?' : 'Not Found';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to find a single word in a string without regular expressions, you can do as follows:

```
function isWordInString(needle, haystack) {
  return haystack
    .split(' ')
    .some(p => (p === needle));
}
isWordInString('hello', 'hello great world!'); // true
isWordInString('eat', 'hello great world!'); // false
```

Advantages over regex:

- Works with non-latin characters like Hebrew
- No need to sanitize the word you search in the string. Some methods in other answers will fail and return a false positive when searching for a "." (dot)