# Test location jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function in jquery that returns the full URL. Based on that I assign active classes to the correct ID's. But one case  tests if the word "fr" is in it (for the language button). But a lot of pages have names containing "frying".

So each time I go on a "frying" page the function gives the "fr" ID an active class.

Is there any way around it?
Full url would be something like: www.example.com/frying/oils or in French: www.example.com/fr/frying/oils

```
$(function() {
  var loc = window.location.href; // returns the full URL 
    if(/fr/.test(loc)) {
    $('#fr').addClass('active');
    $('#en').removeClass('active');
    $('#nl').removeClass('active');
  }

});
```

Comment: What does the full url look like?

Comment: What does a full URL look like?  If the languages are subdirectories, you could check for \/fr\/

Comment: Provide your full URL 1st

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a regex that matches the text "fr" between boundaries characters:

```
if(/\bfr\b/.test(loc)) {

}
```

You may also avoid regex, doing

```
if(loc.indexOf('/fr/') != -1) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`if(/\/fr\//.test(loc)) {` ought to do it.  Check for the entire string that is the subdirectory, with the slashes.

Answer (score 0):

[JavaScript/jQuery - How to check if a string contain specific words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388429/javascript-jquery-how-to-check-if-a-string-contain-specific-words)

Specific excerpt from it that might helpful:

```
function wordInString(s, word){
return new RegExp( '\\b' + word + '\\b', 'i').test(s);
}
```

This will match exact word case insensitive way...