# Compare words in strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, compare, match

I am trying to compare words in strings. This is what i want to do:

```
var string1 = "Action, Adventure, Comedy";
var string2 = "Action Horror";

if (string1 have a word from string 2 == true)
{
    alert("found!");
}
```

I have tried match() but in my situation, it tries to find "Action Horror" instead of "Action" and "Horror" words.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21081760/4689622

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript/jQuery - How to check if a string contain specific words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388429/javascript-jquery-how-to-check-if-a-string-contain-specific-words)

Comment: A possibly related scenario: [sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this using **[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** and **[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)**

```js
var string1 = "Action, Adventure, Comedy";
var string2 = "action Horror";

var strArr = string1.match(/\b\w+?\b/g)
  //getting all words from string one
  .map(function(v) {
    return v.toLowerCase();
  });
//converting strings to lower case for ignoring case

var res = string2.match(/\b\w+?\b/g)
  // getting words from second string
  .reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a || strArr.indexOf(b.toLowerCase()) != -1;
    //checking string in first word  array
  }, false);
  // also set initial value as false since no strings are matched now

console.log(res);
```

Or

```js
var string1 = "Action, Adventure, Comedy";
var string2 = "action Horror";

var res = string2.match(/\b\w+?\b/g)
  // getting words from second string
  .reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a || new RegExp('\\b' + b + '\\b', 'i').test(string1);
    //checking string in first string
  }, false);
  // also set initial value as false since no strings are matched now

console.log(res);
```

Refer : [JavaScript/jQuery - How to check if a string contain specific words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388429/javascript-jquery-how-to-check-if-a-string-contain-specific-words/21081760#21081760)

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `String.split`, `String.indexOf` and `Array.foreach` functions:

```
var string1 = "Action, Adventure, Comedy, Horror";
    var string2 = "Action Horror";

    var str1_arr = string1.split(', ');
    str1_arr.forEach(function (v) {
        if (string2.indexOf(v) !== -1) {
            console.log("string '"+ v +"'(from string1) was found in string2 in position " + string2.indexOf(v));
        }
    });

// the output:
string 'Action'(from string1) was found in string2 in position 0
string 'Horror'(from string1) was found in string2 in position 7
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Answer (score -1):

Declare two sets:

```
    var Set set1,ser2;
```

Copy string1 into set1 and string2 into set2

(Not sure how to do this).  Then have:

var intersection = new Set([x for (x of set1) if (set2.has(x))]);

```
    if intersection.prototype.size>0
```

There are words common to both strings (and sets).