# Checking for a Specific Word in a Discord Message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to figure out how to get a specific word from an entire message. Like using a profanity filter.

```
    for (let x = 0; x < profanities.length; x++) {
    if (message.content.toUpperCase().includes(profanities[x].toUpperCase())) {
        message.channel.send('Oooooooh you said a bad word!');
        client.channels.get('484375912389935126').send(`Message was deleted due to use of a blocked word:\n\n"${message.content}"`);
        message.delete();
        return;
    }
}
```

Now this works except for the fact that if a word was said inside another word it finds it too because of the .includes like if I were to block "bum" and someone says "bumble" it would delete "bumble" as well. That's all well and good for profanity filters but I wanted to do a fun one for a member:

```
    const words = message.content.toLowerCase();
    if (words.includes('bum')) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          message.channel.send('Are we talking about <@memberID>?!');
        }, 1500);
    }
```

I used "memberID" instead of the real ID. But this finds "bum" in "bumble" but I only want it to find "bum" as a separate word within the message. Like "This bum is weird" or something like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript/jQuery - How to check if a string contain specific words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388429/javascript-jquery-how-to-check-if-a-string-contain-specific-words)

Comment: @SuperStormer Yup, specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21081760/6525260) should solve the issue (Most of the other answers are blatantly wrong).

Comment: @ArnavBorborah the accepted answer is the same thing

Comment: @SuperStormer the answer I linked is more generalized.

Comment: While these are basically what I wanted, I'm not really sure how they work since I'm a bit new to js. I probably should've mentioned that earlier

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers say, use regex:

```js
if (/\bbum\b/i.test(message.content)) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    message.channel.send('Are we talking about <@memberID>?!');
  }, 1500)
}
```

The `\b` checks for a word boundary and the `i` makes it case-insensitive.