# How do I check for a word in a message, in discord js?

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm trying to make a simple discord bot. How can I make it so it checks for a word inside a message? For example if somebody says "i love bananas" and the trigger word is banana, the bot responds with "same". All I could figure out is how to make it reply to a specific message (like only "banana"), how do I make something like the example I made?

Comment: string has "indexOf" which returns the index if exist and -1 if not

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: Please add the code where you read and process the discord message to your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388429/javascript-jquery-how-to-check-if-a-string-contain-specific-words

Answer (score 1):

`discord.js v13.5.1`

```
const client = new Client({
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES],
});

const triggerWords = ['banana', 'fire', 'white'];

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return false;

  triggerWords.forEach((word) => {
    if (message.content.includes(word)) {
      message.reply(message.content);
    }
  });
});
```

> https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageCreate