# Live search table with inputs fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, filter

Hope you can help me with this.

I'm trying to make a live search for a html table and i got it to work when each cell only contained text's. I then changed the text to input type="text" so that i can toggle read only.
Now i'm trying to search the table and it works to 50%.  I want to be able to search all inputs in each row as i did with text but it only takes the first input of each row now and i'm stuck.

Here is my code:
Table wrapped table > tbody

```
<form method="post" action="'. $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] .'" >
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $row['id'] . '">
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: 700;">
                        <input class="name" type="text" name="name" value="' . $row['name'] . '" readonly>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="phone" value="' . $row['phone'] . '" readonly>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="email" value="' . $row['email'] . '" readonly>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="business_name" value="' . $row['business_name'] . '" readonly>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="title" value="' . $row['title'] . '" readonly>
                    </td>

                    <td class="actions send">
                        <a href="mailto:'. $row['email'] .'">
                        <i class="fa fa-send"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>

                    <td class="actions edit">
                        <button type="submit" name="edit_people">
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                        </button>
                    </td>

                    <td class="actions contacted">
                        <button type="submit" name="contacted_people" value="' . $row['contacted'] . '">
                        <i class="fa fa-comment" style="' . $switch . '"></i>
                        </button>
                    </td>

                    <td class="actions remove">
                        <button type="submit" name="remove_people">
                        <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </form>
```

It loops trough my DB and outputs multiple TR

and here is my jquery

```
$("#Search").keyup(function() {
            _this = this;
            // Show only matching TR, hide rest of them
            $.each($('.addressbook tbody tr'), function() {
              if ($(this).find('input[type="text"]').val().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1)
                $(this).hide();
              else
                $(this).show();
            });
          });
```

Hope you can help me with this.
Best / Fredrik

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Live search through table rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433304/live-search-through-table-rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var searchstring;
$("#Search").keyup(function() {
    searchstring = $(this).val();

    $.each($('.addressbook tbody tr'), function() {
        if($(this).find('input[type="text"][value*="'+searchstring+'"]').length > 0 || searchstring.trim().length == 0){
            // show
            $(this).show();
        }else{
            // hide
            $(this).hide();
        }

    });
});
```

check out examples of regex in the [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) if needed

Comment: Works great, but i just noticed that if i clear my #Search input all fields are gone.  any idea?

Comment: I have updated the answer, I added the empty string condition ( searchstring.trim().length == 0 )