# Jquery: Doing a search on second column of a table

Tags: jquery, search

With reference to  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433304/live-search-through-table-rows) for live search through table rows, the answer illustrates how to search through first column with the following statement:

```
var id = $row.find("td:first").text();
```

My requirement is to search through second column. Replacing `first` with `second` is not working.

Comment: use `nth-child` search the css Syntax to find the second TD.

Comment: @ReyanTropia you mean `nth-child(n)` ? where `n` refers column number ?

Comment: Yes. Or you can also use the answer below for `index` basically `eq(1)` will get u the second child

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector) selector:

```
var id = $row.find("td:eq(1)").text();
```

Index starting from 0.

---

You may also use css selector [:nth-child](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) instead. There's no `:second` or like `:third` selectors in css. The css selector only accepts `:first-child, :last-child` selectors and the jQuery utilize them using shorthand `:first` and the `:last` selector. So, you can use `:first, :last, :first-child, :last-child` in jQuery selector.

```
var id = $row.find("td:nth-child(2)").text();
```

The `:nth-child` index starts with 1.

Comment: Tested both methods. Working Fine. It would be helpful for all if you can give whole code with respect to the referenced question. Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Another way to search through cells of 2nd column is to use [`nth-of-type()` CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp).

```
$('td:nth-of-type(2)').each(function(index){
    $(this).text();
})
```

Comment: :nth-of-type is used for different case.

Comment: I think it can be used here "The `:nth-of-type(n)` selector matches every element that is the nth child, of a particular type, of its parent."