# How to pass the Input value with Table data In Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi All I need help i'm new on Js.
I generate **4 table and 4 input field** under the loop of "JSP".

**My Question is how to pass the Table value with input field value both in Function**

> Input field value and Table value pass in "myFunction(inputvalue,
>   table)" for filter

I add the value of input in "myFunction(this.value)" but i'm stuck. how to add the table values in that function

```
<div class="w3-container">
  <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-padding" type="text" placeholder="Search for names.." id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction(this.value)">

  <table class="w3-table-all" id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
      <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
      <td>Sweden</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction(searchValue, TableId) {
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the id of the table as the second parameter so that you can refer that inside the function body.

```
onkeyup="myFunction(this.value, 'myTable')"
```

Try the following way:

```js
function myFunction(searchValue, TableId) {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  filter = searchValue.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById(TableId);
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-container">
  <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-padding" type="text" placeholder="Search for names.." id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction(this.value, 'myTable')">

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr class="header">
      <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
      <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
      <td>Sweden</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just pass the id of the table and use the [document API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) to use the table.

Here is an example using `document.querySelectorAll()` for your problem:

```js
function myFunction(searchValue, TableId) {
  var entries = document.querySelectorAll("#"+TableId+" > tbody > tr");
  var re = new RegExp(searchValue, "i");
  for(var i = 0; i < entries.length; ++i) {
    var name = entries[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerHTML;
    entries[i].style.display = name.match(re) ? "" : "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-container">
  <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-padding" type="text"
   placeholder="Search for names.." id="myInput"
   onkeyup="myFunction(this.value, 'myTable')">

  <table class="w3-table-all" id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
        <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
        <td>Sweden</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either do something like this:

```
function myFunction(searchValue, TableId) {
  console.log(document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML.search(searchValue) > 0);
}
```

This would check if the search string is in the table and output true or false.

Or you could do it with jQuery, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433304/live-search-through-table-rows) might help.
(Possible duplicate of linked Question, I cannot comment yet. :/)