# How to check an entire string if it contains a specific word using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need help on checking a certain word if it contains in a string that is being assigned into my input textbox.
For example below, If there's a string value assigned to this textbox

```
<input type="text" id="StartLocation" name="StartLocation" value="1 AAC, MT SECTION, RAF SCAMPTON, LINCOLN, LN1 2ST, UNITED KINGDOM" >
```

I want to check if it contains the word "**UNITED KINGDOM**" and if does not, it should return false.
I tried something like this below but it keeps returning true because the alert message is always 'It contains United Kingdom' even though I already
change the value.

```
if ($("input#StartLocation:contains('UNITED KINGDOM')")) {
  alert('It contains United Kingdom');
} else {
  alert('It does not contains United Kingdom');
}
```

How do I fix this? Thanks...

Comment: `:contains` is for matching the text of container elements like `DIV` and `SPAN`, it doesn't match the value of inputs.

Comment: `contains` doesn't check attributes ... perhaps you want to check `[value*='UNITED KINGDOM']` - e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/xmkj07jh/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery string contains check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728022/jquery-string-contains-check)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
if ($("#StartLocation").val().indexOf('UNITED KINGDOM') >= 0) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't use `:contains` to test the value of an `<input>` element, it's for containers like `<div>` and `<span>`. Use `.val()` to get the value, and then use ordinary string methods.

```
if ($("input#StartLocation").val().indexOf("UNITED KINGDOM") != -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way. Use `indexOf`.

```js
var value = $("#StartLocation").val();
if(value.indexOf("UNITED KINGDOM") != -1)
  alert("true");
else
  alert("false");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="StartLocation" name="StartLocation" value="1 AAC, MT SECTION, RAF SCAMPTON, LINCOLN, LN1 2ST, UNITED KINGDOM">
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this approach, because it's more readable. But please check browser compatibility first.

```
if ($("#StartLocation").val().includes('UNITED KINGDOM')) {
  //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `val()` and `indexOf`

```
if ($("input#StartLocation").val().indexOf('UNITED KINGDOM')>-1)) {
   //.. ToDO
}
```