# How to check whether the content of the field contains part of the second field?

Tags: jquery

I have a code that checks if both fields have the same value:

```
$ampD.blur(function() {
      setInterval(update, 1000);

      function update() {
        if ($('input#autocompletegoogle').attr('value') == $('input#field-address').attr('value')) {
          $ampD.attr('style', '');
        } else {
          $ampD.attr('style', 'border: 1px solid #f00!important;background: #ffefef !important');
        }
```

But sometimes `$('input#autocompletegoogle')` contains additionals marks example:

```
"5611JM Eindhoven, Netherlands"
```

but input#field-address contains `"Eindhoven, Netherlands"` and I get false.

How can I check in whether $('input#autocompletegoogle') contains value from $('input#field-address')?

I tried to find the solution almost one hour... I could find right information. Somone could help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery string contains check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728022/jquery-string-contains-check)

Comment: Can you provide a working example with the data you're trying to process?

Answer (score 0):

Simply modify your `if` condition to use something like [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) instead of `==`.

```
var fieldAddress = $('input#field-address').val().toLowerCase();
var autoCompleteGoogle = $('input#autocompletegoogle').val().toLowerCase();

if (autoCompleteGoogle.includes(fieldAddress)) {
    //Auto Complete Google contains Field Address
}
```

If you'd prefer it remain case-sensitive, you can remove the `toLowerCase()` from each.